# A question about the PDE: $u_t-\Delta u=au-bvu$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

Consider the following system of partial differential equations (see [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039607000137) for more details):[image]

[image]

I just want to know how the author got that expression after multiplying by $u^-$ and integrating over $\Omega$ in the proof of Lemma 2.3. I think the function $u^-=\min(0,u)$ is not differentiable  in time.

Comment: It depends on the regularity of $u$, if $u\in H^1(0,T, L^2(\Omega))$ then this is valid.

Comment: @daw here $u$ is proved to be smooth in an earlier result, but my problem is $min(0,u)$ is not differentiable unlike $u$.

Comment: But $u^{-}$ is weakly differentiable, let's define $u^{-}=\text{min} \{0,u\}=\begin{cases} u, ~x\in A \\ 0, ~\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ 
$$\int_\Omega \phi' u^{-} = \int_A \phi' u =-\int_A \phi u'=:-\int_\Omega \phi w$$
therefore $u^{-}$ is weakly differentiable with derivative $w:=\begin{cases} u', ~x \in A \\ 0, ~\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: @MarvinF I still don't know how the author got this integral inequality in the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_t-\Delta u = au-buv \tag{RD} $$

As written, let's multiply (RD) by $u^{-}:=\text{min} \{0,u \}$ and integrate over $\Omega$ we get

$$ \underbrace{\int \partial_t u \ u^{-}}_{(1)} ~\underbrace{- \int \Delta u \ u^{-}}_{(2)}=\underbrace{\int u(a-bv)u^{-}}_{(3)}$$

Now notice that by Green and by the homogenous Dirichlet boundary we get

$$(2)=- \int \Delta u\ u^{-}=\int \nabla u \ \nabla u^{-}-\int_\Gamma \partial_n u \ u^{-}=\int \nabla u \ \nabla u^{-}$$

and  $$(3)=\int u(a-bv)u^- \leq C \int (u^{-})^2$$
since $u \leq u^-$. Lastly notice that as written in my comment above that the weak derivative (both valid for time and space derivative) of $u^{-}$ is given by

$$(u^{-})'=\begin{cases} u', &u\geq0 \\ 0, &u<0 \end{cases}$$
and therefore by the definition of weak derivatives with an appropriate test function one gets $$\int \partial_t u^ \ u^-=\int \partial_t u^- \ u^-~ \text{ and } ~\int \nabla u \ \nabla u^-=\int \nabla (u^-) \ \nabla u^-$$ (valid for integration on $\Omega$ by extending with $0$) and finally with the chain rule $$(1)=\int u^- \partial_t u^-=\int \frac12 \frac{d}{dt} (u^-)^2$$ we get

$$\frac12 \frac{d}{dt} \int (u^-)^2+\int (\nabla u^-)^2=\int u(a-bv)u^- \leq C \int (u^-)^2 $$

Comment: Why $\int (u^-)'=\int u'$ and $\int \nabla (u^-)=\int \nabla u$ ? The equality $\int \nabla (u^-)=\int \nabla u$  may hold if you integrate on the set $A_t=\{x\in \Omega: u(t,x)\leq 0 \}$, but for the equality $\int (u^-)'=\int u'$ we have a spatial integral and a time derivative.

Comment: @user165633 Thank you for your comment, you are correct. I meant $\int \partial_t u \ u^- = \int \partial u^- \ u^-$ instead of $\int \partial_t u = \int \partial_t u^-$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there some results dealing with interchanging weak derivatives and integrals such us $\frac{d}{dt} \int (u^-)^2=\int \frac{d}{dt} (u^-)^2$? it seems a lot of things that work for classical derivatives work also for weak derivatives. No wonder they gave the guy who invented them the Fields Medal :)

Comment: @user165633 Yes, there is. Look for example at the book 'Nonlinear functional analysis and its applications 2.A' by Zeidler for a proof. Temam also uses  in his book 'Navier Stokes Equations' this result
$$ \int \frac{d}{dt} u_m(t)^2 \, dx= 2 \int u_m'(t) u_m(t) \, dx= \frac{d}{dt} \int u_m(t)^2 \, dx$$ for $u \in L^2(0,T;H_0^1)$, so under enough regularity it holds.

Comment: @user165633 If you are interested in a proof, there is one in these lecture notes https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6A.pdf on page 208, but done in a more abstract setting.

Comment: Thanks again for sharing this!

Comment: Sorry but how do you get the inequality $(3)$? don't you need $v\geq0$?