# Weak derivative of $u^-:=\min\{0,u\}$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, integration-by-parts

This is related to [This Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201155/a-question-about-the-pde-u-t-delta-u-au-bvu) when I want to show that if a function $u$ has a strong derivative then the function $u^-:=\min \{0,u\}$ has a weak one. This is my question:

Let $I=(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $u:I\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function and $\phi\in C^\infty_c(I)$  (smooth compactly supported function), then by integration by parts
$$\int_a^bu(t)\phi'(t)\,dt=-\int_a^bu'(t)\phi(t)\,dt.$$
Let $I_1=\{t\in I: u(t)\leq 0 \}$. Do we have
$$\int_{I_1}u(t)\phi'(t)\,dt=-\int_{I_1}u'(t)\phi(t)\,dt$$
and why ?

Comment: Can you answer this when $I_1$ is an interval, e.g. if $u$ is convex?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Yes, in this case $u$ being continuous, it must vanish in the extremities of $I_1$.

Comment: OK, so how can you extend this? What does the definition $I_1 = \{ u \le 0 \}$ tell you about the topology of $I_1$? (I think perhaps working with $\{ u < 0 \}$ makes the next step more obvious.)

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Maybe splitting $\{u<0\}$ into a countable union of open intervals.

Comment: Yup, that's the idea.